# Game Development Unity3D Free or Paid level?

Tags: unity

I am going to develop an iOS/Android game. I want to choose a TOOL to start game development.

I went thought Unity 3D. I read its not free. I also read that we need to pay them for getting native code.

Can any one explain three questions coming in my mind.

1. I code in JavaScript, using Unity3D. When I want to upload it to AppStore and Play Store, will they convert to Java & Objective-C/Swift, or it remains same.
2. If I  develop, upload final game build to App Store, PlayStore, Do I need to pay Unity, or I can upload in free?
   3.Can I integrate Ads/Google/Chartboost or any kind of Ads, in Free, or I need to pay for that too?

Thanks.

Comment: Please only ask one question per post. Further, if you search the site, I think you'll find answers to a few of these questions. -1 for no evidence of research.

Comment: I agree with Byte56. Use google and this site's search feature in future!

Comment: Thanks Guys. I will take care of it next time. I will ask one question per post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The deployed file contains the [Mono](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29) Runtime. On build, your C#, JS and/or Boo code is turned into [CIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) code which is packaged with the runtime. So now the Mono runtime can run that CIL code on your phone - that's what a deployed Unity game is. P.S. Why does it matter?
2. You can upload free. Unity changed their licensing about a year ago to be much more permissive - you get many features which were previously Pro-only, and you don't have to pay for anything unless and until your game meets or exceed $100k (USD) gross revenues.

Comment: How will Unity gets one's revenue has crossed $100 USD/year?

Comment: Also, Is it true that one cannot change Launch Screen in Free Unity?

Comment: 1. I think you'll find they just keep an eye on Unity games that have made it big? You also do have a license even if you're a free user,  BTW. Maybe someone else can answer that better. But I don't think you need to worry about exceeding $100k  at this stage :) 2. Of course you can't. Goodness - they are giving away their top notch engine and development environment to you FOR FREE, they should at least get some advertising out of it!

Comment: Thanks. I am much clear, a very last comment, Should I go for Unity or go for Cocos2d? Just in one line I want your suggestion.

Comment: No, I won't answer that, sorry. We deal with concrete questions that have concrete answers. We don't recommend starting technologies here - if you had asked that as your question, it would have been closed. You need to do your own research based on your own criteria. If you want to chat, use the chat feature of the site. Also in future you will please ask one question and you will get ONE answer. You're welcome.

Comment: Thanks, Your answer helped me. I am doing more research. I will put new Question, If any more confusion comes in my mind. Thanks.

Comment: The first point is why unity games tend to be 5x larger than they should be.

Comment: 5x larger in size? @Bálint

Comment: @V S yes, in datasize. Especially for mobile devices.